# Is there a rate calculator utility in unix/bash?

Tags: bash, unix, command, tail, rate

I am looking for a tool which does something similar to

`tail -f /var/log/some.log | grep EVENT1 |rate`

which keeps displaying the rate of the event.

Comment: rate with respect to the entire log? I'm thinking `wc` to get started.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
tail -f /var/log/some.log | grep --line-buffered EVENT1 | pv -l > /dev/null
```

[`pv` is a pipe monitor](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pv), which outputs statistics on `stderr`; the `-l` will measure lines instead of bytes.

You'll need to use `--line-buffered` on your `grep` call, so that it doesn't buffer larger blocks, or for a general case you can use [`stdbuf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) to adjust your buffering.

Comment: I like the way you think :) You're a bit slower than me, but I didn't know about `-l` to pv, so +1

Comment: @sehe Thanks! Yeah. I think we spent the same 90 seconds testing our respective `pv`s in a shell before posting pretty similar things. Likewise +1 to you for the example output.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean events/second:

```
while read line; do echo -n "$(grep -c EVENT1 <<<"$line")"; done | pv >/dev/null
```

This uses [`pv`](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/unix-utilities-pipe-viewer/), an extremely simple utility. `sudo apt-get install pv` on most distrubutions (or `yum -i` etc.)

Output, when the input is e.g. `(while true; do echo yes; sleep .1; done)`:

```
218B 0:00:22 [9,88B/s] [    <=>       ]
```

The technique used is to replace each matching line with a single byte in the output (namely `'1'`) and just measure output bandwith in bytes-per-second :)